# AWS Elasticsearch VPC hostname not found but curl works on the same address

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, networking, amazon-vpc

I have a [AWS Elasticsearch Service](https://aws.amazon.com/it/elasticsearch-service/) cluster running inside a VPC. Inside the same VPC I have an EC2 instance where I can connect through SSH.
AWS ES gives you an endpoint which works only inside the VPC, something like:

https://your-es-domain-xyz.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/

This is an internal VPC address.

My question is why, from the EC2 in the same VPC, the following curl GET works

```
curl -X GET https://your-es-domain-xyz.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/


{
  "name" : "T-FDryG",
  "cluster_name" : "617090640476:es-domain",
  "cluster_uuid" : "xyz",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.8.0",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "65b6179",
    "build_date" : "2019-01-01T00:47:46.026972Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But host or ping commands return an unknown hostname?

```
ping https://your-es-domain-xyz.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/

ping: unknown host https://your-es-domain-xyz.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/
```

```
host https://your-es-domain-xyz.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/

Host https://your-es-domain-xyz.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/ not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing / at the end for host command? Also ping might not work if AWS Elasticsearch or EC2 associated security group does not allow ICMP traffic in/out